# .ajax not being invoked

Tags: jquery

I've got a javascript function I created.  Somewhere in that function, this line is called:

```
var divContent = getDataAsyncHtml(dialogDiv.attr("winHref"));
```

I'm not sure why the .ajax is not being invoked once it hits my getDataAsyncHtml function.  Do I need a function() ?

```
function getDataAsynHtml(urlWithContent)
{
    alert("urlWithContent: " + urlWithContent);

    // jQuery async request
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: urlWithContent,
        success: function(data) {
            return $('.result').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the alert message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an error function to see if you are just not getting a success returned.

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlWithContent,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    }, error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will never get alert in $.ajax function you wrote, because alert goes after return ... . It must look like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: urlWithContent,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
        return $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
```